# Hibernate orphanRemoval removes my parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a **tree structure** that I call a graph, that uses the [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Class **Graph** has

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "graphEntry", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
public List<GraphNode> getStartNodes() {
    return startNodes;
}

public void addStartNode(GraphNode graphNode){
    startNodes.add(graphNode);
    graphNode.setGraphEntry(this);
}

public void removeStartNode(GraphNode graphNode){
    startNodes.remove(graphNode);
    graphNode.setGraphEntry(null);
}
```

and **GraphNode** has:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "graphEntry")
public Graph getGraphEntry() {
    return graphEntry;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = GraphNode.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent")
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
public GraphNode getParentNode() {
    return parentNode;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
@OptimisticLock(excluded = true)
public List<GraphNode> getChildNodes() {
    return childNodes;
}
```

When I replace startNode with different node, I get

`PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ...GraphNode`

When I change the order of 2 nodes my data are correctly saved in DB.

I tried to change cascade type to PERSIST and MERGE instead of having ALL but it doesn't help. It looks like hibernate is deleting Graph when the old startNode does not point there any more.

How can I ensure that my Graph is not being removed and node replacement works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behavior when you set `orphanRemoval` to true; it tells if the child is orphaned. it should also be removed from the database.

Let's understand this with an example, Let's say you have `Employee` entity and Employee can have multiple accounts.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    private Integer employeeId;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<Account> accounts;
}
```

It essentially means that whenever we remove  ‘account from accounts set’(which means I am removing the relationship between that account and Employee); the account entity that is not associated with any other Employee on the database (i.e. orphan) should also be deleted.

Comment: In your case yes, however my example is a bit different since another Node will have a reference to this Graph.